# QuartusII Synthesis: Enumerated type to State signals (encoding)

Tags: enums, verilog, system-verilog, fsm, quartus

I am designing an FSM in SystemVerilog for synthesis through the QuartusII (14.1) tool to put on an Altera FPGA. I am using an enum declaration to make the code much more reasonable:

```
typedef enum logic [7:0] { CMD_INIT,
                           CMD_WAIT,
                           CMD_DECODE,
                           CMD_ILLEGAL,
                           CMD_CMD0,
                           ... } cmd_st;
...
cmd_st cs, ncs;
...
```

Whenever Quartus synthesized this state machine, it seems to create a one-hot encoding despite the `logic [7:0]` part of the type. As in, when I got to add the states to SignalTap, I get all of the states as a signal 1-bit variable (`cs.CMD_INIT`, `cs.CMD_WAIT`, etc). While this is usually pretty useful, as I need to see a bunch of these states and some over values at once, I am running out of on-chip memory to contain all of these states (there are well over 8 of them; like 50+). So adding all of them to SignalTap takes ALOT of this memory; but if I could just put down the 8-bit value for `cs`, I would have plenty of space for other things.

I cant figure out how to get Quartus to NOT use the 1-hot encoding for the FSM. I have tried changing the settings (Settings->Compiler Settings->Advance Settings (Synthesis...)->State Machine Processing) to Minial Bits, User Encoding and Sequential, as well as added values for a few of the states:

```
typedef enum logic [7:0] { CMD_INIT           = 8'd0,
                           CMD_WAIT           = 8'd1,
                           CMD_DECODE         = 8'd2,
                           CMD_ILLEGAL        = 8'd3,
                           CMD_CMD0,
```

(Note, not all of them as there are a bunch of I might add even more in the middle)

Im not sure what else to do so that SignalTap sees only 8-bits for the states (which probably goes back to getting Quartus to synthesize this FSM as sequential rather than 1hot encoding)

Comment: Try using the SM coding guidelines given [here](https://www.altera.com/en_US/pdfs/literature/hb/qts/qts_qii51007.pdf) on page `13-66`. It could be that the synthesizer is not inferring the state machine correctly.

Comment: In particular it says ". If you do not
specify the enumerated type as int unsigned, a signed int type is used by default. In
this case, the Quartus II integrated synthesis synthesizes the design, but does not infer
or optimize the logic as a state machine."

Comment: @EugeneSh. Its definitely determining this is an FSM (it has it under the "State Machines" report). Im oging to try changing the type to see what it says. I did just notice a warning telling me "cannot use minimal number of bits to encode state machine" so that might be part of it. Though when I look under the State Machine report for the FSM in question, I get the encoding I expect (6-bit, sequential). But I cannot find this in SignalTap :(

Comment: @EugeneSh. I tried changing the type to int unsigned but Quartus behaves the same; Im pretty sure its identifying the state machine correctly and possibly even internally representing the FSM correctly based on the report; however SignalTap doesnt seem to have access to the encoded cs lines... and thats what I need...

Comment: How are are declaring your case statement? `case(cs)`, `unique case(cs)` `priority case(cs)` or a `case(1'b1)` variations? The `case(1'b1)` variations are very common for 1-hot. `unqiue` makes forces the parallel_case full_case directives.

Comment: @Greg Just `case (cs)`

Comment: Interesting... Do you get the same result If you convert to parameters instead of a enum? Also try keep the enum but declare `cs,ncs` as `logic[7:0]` or `byte` (static cast if necessary). Might be a bug with the synthesizer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use synthesis pragmas to guide Quartus to use a specific encoding scheme for the state variables. This [page](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/programmable/quartushelp/current/index.htm#hdl/vlog/vlog_file_dir_syn_encoding.htm) gives you details on how to encode state machines using "sequential" encoding thereby avoiding the default one-hot encoding.